# Xcode 7.0 beta 6 crashes when app is run in the simulator with "Xcode quit unexpectedly." error

Tags: ios, xcode7-beta6

My app is crashing in Xcode 7.0 beta 6 when I run it in the simulator with following error message:

> Xcode quit unexpectedly.
>
> Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

Here is my crash report:

http://pastebin.com/YechkXrm

Things I noticed:

1. The crash happens **100% of the time** so I am unable to run my app in the simulator or execute unit tests.
2. **Same app** does NOT crash on a different computer running **identical** OS X and Xcode versions.
3. A different app did not crash.

What I tried so far:

1. Reinstalling Xcode.
2. Reseting content and settings of the simulator.
3. Clearing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/` directories.
4. Deleting and adding the simulator from Window > Devices.
5. Xcdode > Preferences > Source Control > Uncheck the Enable Source control.
6. Selecting "Command line tools" version from Preferences > Locations.
7. Restarting my computer.

I did submit a bug report to Apple.

Xcode Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o)
OS X Version 10.10.5 (14F27)

### Mystery solved

I found out the source of the problem. I am using Carthage to build frameworks. To solve this problem I needed to run `carthage update`. I think that last time I did that I did not commit the built framework files from **Carthage/Build** directory. And maybe when I installed newer Xcode version it caused the problem with the framework files there were built using previous command line tools.

Comment: XCode 7 is now beta and it's normal, that it's crashed sometimes. Have you tried to launch your code in stable XCode version, why you need to use beta?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. I need to use beta because we are using Swift 2.0 in our app.

Comment: Do you have TokenLock installed?

Comment: @CaptJak no, I do not have TokenLock installed.